# Elasticsearch Two sibling aggregations cannot have the same name

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm running Elastic 1.4.4 and have created some code with a range aggregation and a sub-aggregation (cardinality).
If I run my code with a matchall query and some filterquery to get a subset all works fine.

I see the range aggregation and the expected values for the sub-aggregation.

But as soon as I add a query things fall apart.
I run into an error: "Two sibling aggregations cannot have the same name".

This seems strange since I have the same aggregation/sub-aggregation defined before without any problem.

This is basically what I do:

```
SearchResponse response = 
client.prepareSearch(esIndex)
.setQuery(query)
.setFrom(startAt)
.setSize(topSize)
.addAggregation(AggregationBuilders.cardinality(UNIQUE_IPS).field(Constants.MAIN_COLLAPSE_FIELD))
.addAggregation(collapse)
.addAggregation(filtersetbranche)              \
.addAggregation(Constants.FTE_RANGES_AGGS.subAggregation(AggregationBuilders.cardinality("ftecounts").field(Constants.MAIN_COLLAPSE_FIELD)))
.execute()
.actionGet();
```

Comment: It would really help if you added a complete example that reproduces the issue. It's difficult to figure out what's going on based on the bits and pieces provided.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue.

I added a subaggregation to the Constants.FTE_RANGES_AGGS dynamically.
So, the first time I call this piece of code all is fine.
But the next time I added the same subaggregation with the same name hence the error "Two sibling aggregations cannot have the same name".

So, I have to rewrite it to use a copy of the Constant or do it in a different way.